An inequality in regularised incomplete beta function
Let $I_p(a, b)$ be the regularised incomplete beta function, i.e.
$$ I_p(a, b) = \frac{B_p(a, b)}{B(a, b)} $$
where $B_p(a, b)$ is the incomplete beta function and $B(a, b)$ the beta function, with the relevant parameters.
I want to show the following inequality holds for $a, b > 1$ (integers):
$$ I_x(a+1, b-1) > I_y(a, b) $$
where $x, y \in (0, 1)$ are defined as values such that the following equalities hold:
$$ I_x(a+1, b-2) = 1 - I_x(a, b-1) $$
and
$$ I_y(a, b-1) = 1 - I_y(a-1, b) $$
The inequality appears to be numerically correct for a large range of values I tested, but I have not managed to prove it due to the indirect way that $x$ and $y$ are defined.
Any suggestions? This problem relates to a game-theoretic problem I'm working on. The equalities that define $x$ and $y$ are the 'indifference conditions' for some players in the game, meaning that $x$ and $y$ are values such that these players are indifferent between choosing the LHS or the RHS.
Below is an example where $a = 4$, $b = 7$. The blue dashed line is the value of $y$, while the orange dashed line is the value of $x$. The intercept between $I(a+1,b-1)$ and $x$ is greater than the intercept between $I(a,b)$ and $y$, thus the inequality holds for these values of $a$, $b$.

